# JvmField can only be applied to final property. This warning will become an error in further releases

Tags: java, kotlin

Could anyone clarify as to why this is the case?

I understand in which situations we are unable to use the annotation (outlined in the [official document](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#instance-fields)) but I don't understand what the potential issues are - given that the earlier versions of Kotlin compiles and works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"`JvmField` can only be applied to `final` properties", in other words, you cannot put `JvmField` on *overridable* (or `open`) properties.

Let's say you wrote the following, and it were allowed:

```
open class Foo {
    @JvmField
    open val x = 1
}
```

And not knowing that `x` is actually a `JvmField`, someone else, let's say Bob, inherit `Foo` and try to override `x` with his own getter:

```
class Bar: Foo() {
    override val x get() = (10..20).random()
}
```

Now, I don't have an old version of Kotlin anymore to actually compile this and see what would actually happen here, but I'll use some logic to show that either way, this leads to a confused Bob.

If this code doesn't compile, then it would be quite unexpected for Bob, wouldn't it? `Foo` has an open property `x`, yet when he tries to override it, he cannot! Bob is confused.

If this code does compile, what would it compile to? There would be a `getX` method in the `Bar` class, *which doesn't actually override anything* in `Foo`. Therefore, when Bob does something like

```
fun main() {
    printFooX(Bar())
}

fun printFooX(foo: Foo) {
    // this compiles to an access to an access to the JVM field "Foo.x"
    // because the compiler doesn't know any better
    println(foo.x)
}
```

expecting a number between 10 and 20 to be printed, he would actually get 1, and Bob is confused.

So either way, allowing you to put `JvmField` on overridable properties will cause confusing behaviour such as those described above, so it is better to just not allow it in the first place.

The root of the problem, as you may have realised by now, is that JVM fields, unlike Kotlin properties, are not overridable. Therefore, to make your Kotlin properties into JVM fields, you need to make them not overridable, to prevent "weird things" from happening.

---

`JvmField` also can't be applied to properties marked with `override`, even if it is also marked with `final`, but that's another story. To learn more, [KT-32753](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-32753/Prohibit-JvmField-on-property-in-primary-constructor-that-overrides-interface-property) may be a good start.

Comment: sorry for deleting the comment, didn't meant to post (was editing)

Thanks for the answer, I think I'll need more time to wrap my head around the example you've given. 

I guess, in my mind, I would expect it to compile and the `getX` method would return a number between 10 and 20 without having to override a method in the `Foo` class ...

Comment: @220284 That's what you would expect, right? But I don't think it would actually do that. Like I said, it would probably access the `x` field in `Foo` instead, or even throw some `Error` perhaps? Anyway, my point is that the unexpected behaviour is why they don't allow you to put `JvmField` on overridable properties anymore. (btw I changed it to a better example, just in case the Kotlin compiler actually does smart casting there :D)